# Can't get JSON into array from POST request

Tags: java, json, unirest

I'm using the [Unirest](http://unirest.io/java.html)  library to parse some JSON I'm getting from a MAshape API. I'm new to making HTTP requests in Java, and I'm having trouble understanding the error.

The function I made is:

```
public ArrayList<String> httpPost(int year) {
    HttpResponse<String> response = null;
    try {
        response = Unirest.post("https://--------.p.mashape.com/v1/calculate/" + year)
                .header("X-Mashape-Key", "--------------------------")
                .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                .header("Accept", "application/json")
                //.field("blabla", "blabla")
                .field("filing_status", myFS)
                .field("pay_periods", myPP)
                .field("pay_rate", getGrossPay())
                .field("state", myState)
                .asString();
    } catch (UnirestException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // retrieve the parsed JSONObject from the response
    JSONObject myObj = new JSONObject(response);
    JSONArray results = new JSONArray();
    try {
        results = myObj.getJSONArray("annual"));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    if (results != null) { 
       int len = results.length();
       for (int i=0;i<len;i++){ 
        try {
            list.add(results.get(i).toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
       } 
    }
    return list;
}
```

I get the error:

```
org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["annual"] not found
```

So I outputted the `response` variable to a file, and the file had `com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpResponse@161b062a` in it. I don't know where that came from.

Just to check, I used [hurl.it](https://hurl.it) and the same response I'm putting in to my program yields a successful response:

```
{
  "annual": {
    "state": {
      "amount": 68232.65
    },
    "fica": {
      "amount": 91800
    },
    "federal": {
      "amount": 418014.8
    }
  },
  "per_pay_period": {
    "state": {
      "amount": 5686.05
     },
     "fica": {
      "amount": 7650
    },
    "federal": {
      "amount": 34834.57
    }
  }
}
```

I tried changing the type of `response` from `String` to `JsonNode` but it didn't work and I don't really know how to work with that anyway. I added all the required libraries as well. Any help?

Comment: Replace `myObj.getJSONArray("annual"));` by `myObj.getJSONObect("annual"));`

Comment: `JSONObject["annual"] not found` I thought this would work because it was `annual` was an array but it didn't. Does that mean there is a problem with the JSON I'm getting? There are brackets on the `annual` in the error, does the JSON require brackets around the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `myObj.getJSONObject("annual");`

Comment: `JSONObject["annual"]` not found I thought this would work because it was `annual` was an array but it didn't. Does that mean there is a problem with the JSON I'm getting? There are brackets on the annual in the error, does the JSON require brackets around the array?

Comment: try this way  JSONObject myObj = new JSONObject(response.getBody());JSONObject results = new JSONObject();results = myObj.getJSONObject("annual"));